# Facebook Graph API SSL socket hand shake exception

Tags: java, facebook, sockets, facebook-graph-api, ssl

This is the sample program from which  iam testing the facebook data collection using graph api .in my whole project iam not able to find the root cause of the error .  first time it is collecting the  data from the program . but second time it is showing ssl exception.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Make a URL to the web page
        boolean flag=false;
        int count=0;
        while(true)
        {

            count++;

            if(count==2)
            {

                flag=false;
            }

        System.out.println(new Date());
        URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+message,post_id,created_time,actor_id,attachment,comments,created_time,impressions,likes,message_tags,place,share_count+from+stream+where+source_id+in(select+page_id+from+page+where+username=%27ATT%27)+and+created_time>1368439594&access_token=[HERE STANDS MY ACCESSTOKEN]");
        System.out.println(new Date());
        // Get the input stream through URL Connection
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is =con.getInputStream();

        // Once you have the Input Stream, it's just plain old Java IO stuff.

        // For this case, since you are interested in getting plain-text web page
        // I'll use a reader and output the text content to System.out.

        // For binary content, it's better to directly read the bytes from stream and write
        // to the target file.


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;

        // read each line and write to System.out
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        }
    }
}
```

please guide me in resolving this issue .

Error :

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at span.com.Testing.main(Testing.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is a HTTPS URL which means it uses SSL but you try to open the connection with `URLConnection`. To open the HTTPS URL you should do it with a `HttpsURLConnection`:

```
final HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

With this change, it works for me. ;)